# How to add nested object to exising object in core data

Tags: swift, core-data, ios8, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have one to many objects `Driver <-->> Car`.
Classes:

```
class Driver: NSManagedObject {
   @NSManaged var fullName: String
    @NSManaged var cars: NSSet
}
class Car: NSManagedObject {
   @NSManaged var model: String
   @NSManaged var year: String
   @NSManaged var driver: Driver
}
```

I inserted one Driver and a few car objects.
But I don't know what is the proper way to update car list to add or remove some car object.
Wired but I can't find any example on net how to do this.
So how to just add new car to existing driver or remove car from it?

**UPDATE**
I tried something like this but it saves new car in database but those new cars are not related to driver.
When I fetch driver in `cars:NSSet` I am still getting one car.

```
let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext;

        var newCar:Car = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Car", inManagedObjectContext: context!) as! Car

        newCar.year = "1977";

        var cars = driver?.cars.allObjects as! [Car]

        cars.append(newCar)

        var err: NSError?;

        context?.save(&err);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I just realized you asked for swift, which I don't know. My answer isn't really valid then but let's just hope you can read through it :) The logic is the same anyways so I won't delete it.

I'll quote Mundi's answer by saying that you should use the autogenerated files once you've built your model using the core data model. It's incredibly easy and effective. And fast.

To add a sub-object to your object, you simply need to

1. Fetch or Create your object
2. Create new instances of your sub-objects
3. Add those instances to your "containing" object.
4. Save the `managedObjectContext`

   ```
   //A method that returns your object 
   -(Car*)getCarById:(NSString*)carId inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)context{
       NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Cars" inManagedObjectContext:context];
       NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
       [request setEntity:entityDescription];

       //NSPredicate has to be used to fetch the correct car. I'll assume you know that.

       NSError *error;
       NSArray *array = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
       if (array.count > 0)
           return (array.firstObject);
   }
   ```

If this methods doesn't return your Car/Driver, create it.

```
Car *car = [self getCarById:myId inManagedObjectContext:context];
    if(!car)
    {
        car = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Car" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    }
```

You now HAVE your object(s), and all of it's sub objects if there are any (even with a fault status).

now if I have a `Driver` object (that I got using the same methods), I can simply use

```
[car addDriver:driver];
```

because this method was autogenerated when i created my model.

if you have your driver by himself, you can go upwards and give him another car

```
driver.car = car;
```

I haven't really tested when doing it in that direction but I think you should be fine, core data is pretty powerful when it comes to simple stuff like that.

Also this is all very blurry to me, addDriver: might be addObject or setDriver, maybe insertDriver. I don't fully remember but you should be able to find them in the .h files anyway. :)

Comment: From some reason functions like `addDriver` were not added. I don't know why. But anyway fetching driver and adding it to car object did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

First, variabel names in Core Data, by convention start with lower case letters. Thus, `fullName`, not `FullName`.

Second, you do not write this file yourself. Instead, you use the model editor and have Xcode generate the class files.

In the model editor, establish a to-many relationship `cars`, from the `Driver` entity that points to the `Car` entity. Establish a reverse to-one relationship `driver` from `Car` to `Driver`.

Now you can add a car to a driver like

```
ferrari.driver = niki
```

Comment: Thanks. I exported objects it but I wrote it here by hand :-). I know how to insert it but I don'tknow how to update car year for example or add new car to driver. I updated code in question.

Comment: `car.year = "2011"` , create car, add driver as shown above. You should mark the question as answered because your original question is fully accounted for.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Gil Sand's answer let me write what worked for me in swift when it comes to saving nested objects to coredata.

1. Create your NSManagedObject instance of the parent object entity which u wants to saved in to.

2.Create new instances of your sub-objects

3. Add the instances in to your containing object as key value pairs and save the context

   ```
   for car in cars { 
    //Step 1
      let entity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Car", into: managedObjectContext)

    // Step 2
      let driver_entity =  NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Driver", in: managedObjectContext)

       let driver = Driver(entity: driver_entity, insertInto: managedObjectContext)

      driver.name = "Sean Paul"
      driver.age = "46"

    //Step 3
    entity.setValue(model, forKey: "model")
    entity.setValue(year, forKey: "year")
    entity.setValue(driver, forKey: "driver") // the key name "driver" is the entity relationship name you define in your coredata model

    managedObjectContext.insert(entity)
    }


         do {
               try managedObjectContext.save()
         } catch {
               print("Failed saving car details")
         }
   ```